# looping through a 2d array row using enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I've been scratching my head with this:
The method simply changes an entire row of a 2d array in java.

```
    public void setRow(int x, int newValue){
        if (isValid(x,0)){
            //for(int i: array[x]){
            //    array[x][i] = newValue;
            //}
            for(int i = 0; i < array[x].length; i++){
                array[x][i] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

The second for loop works, the first one does nothing. what am i missing?

Comment: have you used debugger?

Comment: You're mixing up the index of a value in an array and the actual value.

Comment: `for(int i: array[x]){` is iterating over values `array[x]` holds and `i` holds value for each iteration. So if your `array[x]` is lets say `{0,0,0}` then in your loop you are using `array[x][0]` all the time. 

`for (int i = 0; i<array[x].length; i++)` on the other hand is using `i` as index.

Comment: @OP you accepted answer which is only partially correct. It points that in `for(int i : array[x])` `i` represents value not index, but it incorrectly claims that you can assign new value to `i` and change content of array. This is not true because `i` is variable which copies value (and in case of non-primitive types - reference) held in array. But it is still separate variable so by changing it you can't modify array. It is like `int x = values[4]; x=2;` will **not** put `2` in `values[4]`. It will only modify `x` variable.

Comment: @Pshemo indeed... I have removed the accepted answer for now. I think I understand what is happening but I want to try a few thing to make sure...

Comment: I voted to close your question as duplicate (you can see duplicated question at top of your post if you refresh this page). There Jon Skeet nicely explained what is happening here. If you want me to reopen this question let me know why you don't think that this is duplicate.

Comment: Anyway solution you may be looking for is using `Arrays.fill(array[x], newValue);` *instead* of your loop (this method simply uses such loop internally which allows us to shorten our code).

Comment: @Pshemo No need. It is indeed a duplicate. Also kudos for the Arrays.fill part. Does what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `for(int i: array[x])`, `i` isn't the index of your array: it is a reference of an element in your array. It will change to the next element until it reaches the end of the array. Your assignement should logically be `i = newValue` (It won't work though, continue reading).

As an example: imagine you have an array `singleArray = { 4, 2, 1, 4}`.

Writing `for (int i : singleArray) sysout(i);` will give you as output `4214`. This is why your first for loop doesn't work.

Still, why won't `i = newValue` work in this case? It's because `i` is actually only a successive copy of your values in your array. If it was an object, `i` would've been a reference to your object: calling `i.setValue(newValue)` would've worked fine.

**NOTE**: Note that `i = newValue` won't work, contrary to what I said before: you would just override your reference.

Comment: "Your assignement should be `i = newValue`" doesn't make much sense. `i` is local variable separate than variable in array which holds element. If you reassign new value to `i` that will ***not*** affect an array content. In this case solution OP is using is OK (unless he wants to use methods design for this like `Arrays.fill(array, element)`).

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah I'm realizing it won't work with `int`s, tho it would've with `Integer`s. I didn't take that in account.

Comment: @Pshemo I updated my answer to take that into account: I was too focused on answering his question and didn't pay attention at it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not quite, it also wouldn't work for other types, regardless if they are primitive or not. You are probably thinking about *modifying state* of an object not *assigning* new one. So we can have `for(Car c : garage){c.clean();}` which will change state of object (will clean all cars which already are in `garage` array), but if we write `for(Car c : garage){c = new Car();}` this will only assign brand new (and most likely clean) Car only to local `c` variable, it will not change content of garage.